# Ruby library function to transform Enumerable to Hash

Tags: ruby, hash, enumerable

Consider this extension to Enumerable:

```
module Enumerable

  def hash_on
    h = {}
    each do |e|
      h[yield(e)] = e
    end
    h
  end

end
```

It is used like so:

```
people = [
  {:name=>'fred', :age=>32},
  {:name=>'barney', :age=>42},
]
people_hash = people.hash_on { |person| person[:name] }
p people_hash['fred']      # => {:age=>32, :name=>"fred"}
p people_hash['barney']    # => {:age=>42, :name=>"barney"}
```

Is there a built-in function which already does this, or close enough to it that this extension is not needed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Enumerable.to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_h) converts a sequence of `[key, value]`s into a `Hash` so you can do:

```
people.map {|p| [p[:name], p]}.to_h
```

If you have multiple values mapped to the same key this keeps the last one.

Answer (score 5):

```
[   {:name=>'fred', :age=>32},
    {:name=>'barney', :age=>42},
].group_by { |person| person[:name] }

=> {"fred"=>[{:name=>"fred", :age=>32}],
   "barney"=>[{:name=>"barney", :age=>42}]}
```

Keys are in form of arrays to have a possibility to have a several Freds or Barneys, but you can use `.map` to reconstruct if you really need.